# How to insert image into activity

Tags: android, image

I transferred my jpeg image to drawable but there is an error :
failed to convert @drawable/background into a drawable.

```
android:background="@drawable/blue background"
```

^^ there's supposed to be a space in the name ^^ if you're wondering

Comment: do you have a space in the file name ?

Comment: android require all drawables and xmls to be in lowercase and with no spaces!

Comment: change the image name to blue_background and try

Comment: Spaces aren't allowed. The only characters you are allowed are: letters, numbers (not at the beginning), underscore and dot.

Comment: There's **NOT** supposed to be a space in the name, if you're wondering

Answer (score 1):

Failed to convert because all resource names must only contain `[A-Za-z0-9_.]`

In other words, can't have a space.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove your space in your file name,
then you can try android:src="your drawable path"